# Keyword extraction software

Tags: keyword, extract

I am looking for a piece of software that, given some text, will extract the "meaningful" keywords. For example, in the sentence:

```
StackExchange is an online community.
```

I want "StackExchange" and "online community" to be singled out as semantically-meaningful keywords, but not "is" or "an".

A bit of research led to [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/), which does the job well. Are there other solutions out there, especially open source ones?

Comment: Any reason why you dont want to go with Alchemy ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [TexLexan](http://texlexan.sourceforge.net/), which is open source. [This page](http://www.quora.com/What-are-good-tools-to-extract-key-words-and-or-topics-tags-from-a-random-paragraph-of-text) also has good list of open source and commercial options.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old, but I had really good luck building my own tools on top of [MontyLingua](http://web.media.mit.edu/~hugo/montylingua/).