# Existing app that extracts meaningful data from old e-mails?

Tags: email, data-mining

I was wondering if there is an application, and if not if it's worth writing one, that can gather meaningful data from old e-mails. I'm thinking things like:

- Instructions (that could become "5 steps to..." posts)
- Definitions

etc

Any idea? Suggestions? etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can offer the same solution as I did to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057397/keyword-extraction-software/8556083#8556083), that is software like [TexLexan](http://texlexan.sourceforge.net/) or [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) that can find keywords and other summary information. There is also a good list of open source and commercial solutions on [this page](http://www.quora.com/What-are-good-tools-to-extract-key-words-and-or-topics-tags-from-a-random-paragraph-of-text). Definitely easier to see if one of those works then writing your own.